# Attachinary file-upload Thumbnail size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I'm using the Attachinary Gem in Ruby on Rails to upload to Cloudinary.

The file upload form helper auto generates a Thumbnail at 75x75 after upload, and when you edit if it's existing.

Is there a way to change this thumbnail size to represent the correct ratio of the original image?

The upload form helper looks like this at the moment:

```
<%= f.attachinary_file_field(:logo, :cloudinary => { :transformation => {:width=>400, :height=>200, :crop=>:fill }}) %>
```

thanks.

Comment: Fill cropping should retain original proportions. See the documentation for Cloudinary: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#crop_modes

Comment: Sure, it does, but thats not what I'm referring to: After upload, or on edit, the Attachinary gem creates a square thumbnail inline with the form. It's that thumbnail I want to alter. (I can alter it later with some JS, but was hoping there was a Ruby way via Attachinary)